# Ways to backup Azure WAF Resource Configuration/settings

Tags: azure

Please let me  know how to backup Azure WAF Resource Configuration/settings. I am  not able find  anything related to waf backup setting/configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Application Gateway -> Export Template

The template contains all configuration/settings for your WAF

Comment: Thank You  Daniel  for you quick response . How to restore the configuration from template .

Comment: @AbdulMajeed search for template in the portal and you will find "Deploy a custom template". There you just redeploy your template and the settings should be updated or even better use the New-AzResourceGroupDeployment command in powershell.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/deploy-powershell

Answer (score 0):

I appreciate this question is a little old now - the answer already given and accepted is *technically* valid but note that any export of an Application Gateway you do that uses "SSL Certificates" will not include the certificates in the export.

So if you were to try and re-create the Application Gateway from the exported JSON, it will probably not work and may need additional configuration to re-import the SSL certificates referenced by listeners.

For information, you can also use the `Export-AzResourceGroup` cmdlet to export your App Gateway but this too does not include the SSL certificates.

A fairly recent (end of 2020) addition which alleviates this *to some extent* is the ability to pass a reference to a Key Vault certificate but this requires a User Assigned Managed Identity to be associated with the Application Gateway which has permissions to access the certificates and secrets (if they had passwords when added to the Key Vault).

1. Create a user-assigned managed identity - look for Managed Identities in the Azure Portal.
2. Configure your key vault - this basically means add permissions to the Key Vault for the Managed Identity to be able to manage certificates and read secrets.
3. Configure the application gateway. Use the `Set-AzApplicationGatewayIdentity` cmdlet to assign the UA-MI account's ID to the Application Gateway.

The instructions above are abbreviated from this article (which I'll get grief for adding, but I'm not regurgitating documentation here for the sake of it): `https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/key-vault-certs`

Remember that I said the key vault integration alleviates the issue to some extent. Using references still doesn't resolve the issue completely as I believe there are still some pieces of secret information omitted from exports which would be needed to fully re-create the Application Gateway in a working state.